# AzCopy - set public access level for containers

Tags: azure-blob-storage, azcopy

When copying containers from one storage account to another, how can I also "copy" public access level for them? Does such an option exist? Now I had to do this manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there isn't an option for it, you'd need to set public access level for target container by yourself.